# InetAddress.getByName intermittently fails with System error

Tags: java, nslookup

I have some code that uses `InetAddress.getByName` . Intermittently I get a `UnknownHostException`:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: google.com: System error
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1246)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1162)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1098)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1048)
```

Performing `nslookup google.com` works, and the failure itself only happens occasionally.  What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

try to look at [official java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getAllByName%28java.lang.String%29)

> Throws:
>       UnknownHostException - if no IP address for the host could be found, or if a scope_id was specified for a global IPv6 address.